# 1950's/1960's japanese movie (dubbed)

Tags: story-identification, movie

Here's an odd one for you, just stick with me. I am looking for a movie I remember parts of but it was a long time ago.

It was Japanese but it was English dubbed where a group of businessmen were crowded around a ticker-tape machine in a orange-beige room with giant computers, seemingly the whole movie is shot in this room.

one is typing out on the machine, while another is reading from the ticker-tape.

the one reading it says at one point "now lets see if we can read some erotic poems"

that is all I remember honestly, It was on a Turner Classic Movie channel at 2:00 in the morning... if this request does not seem to fall within guidelines, then I will have no problem with this being closed.

Comment: Regarding falling within guidelines, it's unclear to me that this movie is science fiction. If it's not, it's off topic and you might want to ask at the [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com). If it is, please add more details that make the genre clearer. Did the computer possess artificial intelligence, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sci-fi no, but this is undoubtedly Woody Allen's "[What's Up Tiger Lilly?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061177/)" -- the fact that it was an English-dubbed Japanese movie on TCM was the tip-off, and here's the relevant quote: "[And now I will read you some ancient erotic poetry. "There once was a man from Nantucket...](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061177/quotes?item=qt0252699)"